# Swift: read string based on provided user info

Tags: ios, swift, string

On Xcode (Swift) I want to load data stored on the app based on information provided by the user.

For example, the user gives the input of "Xcode":

```
 var userInput = "Xcode"
```

With this information, I want to display the a stored string with the exact same name that is already on the app:

```
 let Xcode = "Xcode is a development tool."
```

This is what I get when I print:

```
 print ("Print: ", userInput) ->      Print: Xcode
```

But I want to print the result from the string value stored from the app instead. The result I'm looking for is this:

```
 print ("Print: ", userInput) ->      Print: Xcode is a development tool.
```

I have to associate the input to the string stored, how can I do this without manually associating thousands of words to the strings I want to show? What is the best approach to get this result?

Thanks!

---

My approach where I have to do one by one is this:

```
 switch userInput {
     case Xcode: // This is the info provided by the user.
         userInput = Xcode // This is the string stored on the app.
     break
 }
```

But once I have thousands of strings this approach is terrible, but works:

```
 print ("Print: ", userInput) ->      Print: Xcode is a development tool.
```

Comment: Am I right that you just want to remove the `_` and add "this is " to the `userInput`? Or what kind of data format you want to achieve?

Comment: On this example yes, but it's just one example. I'm looking for a better way to associate the user input to a string stored on the app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a data model for your information. If you have too much data, I suggest to create a JSON file where each key is the `userInput` with the associated value. Then you can parse the JSON file into a dictionary where you can easily retrieve the key-related value.

At this point you can define your own `print` method that prints the value associated with the key passed as parameter simply using `object(forKey:)` method.

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly understand your question. But what I've understood is to do this with `Dictionary` data type. Here is the sample code for this.

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

var responseMessages : [String : String] = ["" : ""]

if responseMessages[str] == nil
{

   responseMessages[str] = str;
}

print(responseMessages[str]) // Output : Optional("Hello, playground")
```

You know better to remove `optional` keyword from string values by casting them to `String` data type.